# Dealing with multiple fact tables concerning related processes in dimensional modeling

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, star-schema, fact-table

I have the following scenario where OLTP sales data is stored in two separate physical tables:

1. Sales
2. Refunds/Cancellations

A refund always refers to an existing sale (thus 'negating' it), though the dimensions of these tables are nearly the same (date, sales clerk, store, etc.). The data schema looks something like the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sale
(
    sale_id uuid,
    transaction_at timestamp with time zone,
    store_id uuid,
    clerk_id uuid,
    clerk_number bigint,
    currency character varying(3),
    pos_id uuid,
    total numeric,
    net_total numeric
);

CREATE TABLE refund
(
    refund_id uuid,
    sale_id uuid, -- referenced sale to void
    refunded_at timestamp with time zone,
    pos_id uuid,
    clerk_id uuid,
    clerk_number bigint
)
```

I am trying to figure how to model this data for ingstion in a DW. Since I am relatively new to dimensional modeling I have begun reading *The Data Warehouse Toolkit*, but I am as of now unsure of the best approach to handle this case.

To my mind, these are two separate fact tables describing two different business processes (e.g. making a sale and getting a refund), though due to normalization concerns the *refunds* table (besides containing most of the same dimensions) is basically a pointer to a row in the *sales* table (which is fine for OLTP).

Analytical reports down the line would obviously want to look at these in a few ways:

1. All net sales per dimension (gross sales minus refunds)
2. All refund amounts per dimension
3. Other potential business use cases

As is, the first two cases would require joining the fact tables to either subtract the sales amount (case 1) or to get the information on refund amounts (case 2).

The approach that seems to make the most sense for me is something like the following (via some ETL/ELT process):

1. Load the (gross) sales data into a table in the DW
2. Load and denormalize refund data into a table in the DW, joining actual sale data so that amounts etc. are located in the fact table
3. Join either table with common conformed dimensions for further roll-ups and querying

This makes sense to me because:

1. Both fact tables have all required information from the physical event, and
2. There is no explicit dependency between the fact tables, and
3. Common dimensions can be reused

However, in this case, I still would not be able to get the `net sales` without joining these two tables. This makes me think that there should be a separate `net_sale` fact table, but this is problematic:

1. From a business point of view, sales without refunds are the vast majority of events that occur. A `net_sale` table would copy basically 99% of all sale data.
2. From a business *process* point of view, this table would describe an event that does not exist as such (there is no "net sale", only an aggregated view of sales amount per dimension minus refund costs).

Glossing over the third Chapter in *The Data Warehouse Toolkit*, I do not see this case mentioned explicitly (though there might be some parallels w.r.t. factless fact-tables and derived facts). What kind of approach would work in a case like this?

Comment: I would create just 1 fact table and add both sales and refunds to this table. Just add an attribute in one of the dimensions to indicate if it's a sale or refund.

Comment: I thought about that approach as well. However, would that not go against the best practice of having one fact table per measurement event? While this may be warranted (for example, in this case), I did not feel likeI understood the implications enough to go against expert advice.